# how to control options to display in a dropdown with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How to specify how many and what items to be displayed in the dropdown panel of a dropdown control in jQuery (or through any other means)? I am trying to achieve a readonly behavior for dropdown. I cannot make it disabled as it needs to be passed to server. Also adding hidden field is not a viable option at the moment as I have too many controls to update.

My intention is to make the dropdown to list only 1 item, which is nothing but currently selected item.

**Edit**

After going through several threads and options, I got one way of implementing this - remove all the options except selected (or the one that should be stay selected). It seems to be a quick and dirty way of achieving in my case. Wondering if there are any better ways. Here is fiddle i tried: `http://jsfiddle.net/51qqjyk1/1/`

```
$(".readselect").find("option:not(:selected)").remove()
```

Comment: please provide your tries

Comment: Question is not clear could you elaborate with your code .A http://jsfiddle.com might help

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a dropdown in which you cannot select any option?

Then just disable the options individually using `<option disabled="disabled">...</option>`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/d5w51ut3/

```
<select>
    <option disabled="disabled">1</option>
    <option selected="selected">2</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">3</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: small correction, not "cannot select any option" but "cannot change the selection"

Comment: then just use it on select, <select disabled>

Comment: If you disable the entire `select`, you won't be able to open it up to view the options on some browsers. Just disable all the individual options and you won't be able to select any but still see them all. Just add `selected="selected"` on the selected option.